# declare generic class with a generic class as a parameter in swift

Tags: swift

I wrote these simple generic classes and it worked great:

```
class LinkedListNode <T> {
    var value: T
    var next: LinkedListNode<T>?
    weak var prev: LinkedListNode<T>?
    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.next = nil
    }
}

class LinkedList<T> {
    var first: LinkedListNode<T>? = nil
    var last: LinkedListNode<T>? = nil
    var count = 0
    @discardableResult func append(_ value: T) -> LinkedListNode<T> {
        let new = LinkedListNode(value: value)
        new.prev = last
        last?.next = new
        count += 1
        last = new
        if first == nil {
            first = new
        }
        return new
    }
}
```

And I used it like:

```
let list = LinkedList<Int>()
list.append(3)
let lastNode = list.append(5)
```

Now I realized there are some cases when I need to have a customized node: `CustomNode<T>`, subclass of `LinkedListNode<T>`. So I would like to be able to pass the class to be used as the node as:

```
let list = LinkedList<CustomNode<Int>>()
list.append(3)
let customNode = list.append(5)
```

How can I declare my class to have it like this or something similar?

I have tried the following declaration but weird errors rise. Is this even possible?

```
class LinkedList<Node<T>: LinkedListNode<T>> { ...
```

### Update 2019/07/26.

Even with Kamran's approach this method does not compile. I am not sure if this is doable without a protocol. See my comment on Kamran's answer.

```
func remove(node: LinkedListNode<T>) { // change to `func remove(node: U)`
    node.next?.prev = node.prev
    node.prev?.next = node.next
    if node === first {
        first = first?.next
    }
    if node === last {
        last = last?.prev // Error here: "Cannot assign value of LinkedListNode<T>? to U?"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are trying can be achieved as below,

```
class LinkedListNode <T> {
    var value: T
    var next: LinkedListNode<T>?
    weak var prev: LinkedListNode<T>?
    required init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        self.next = nil
    }
}

class GenericCustomNode<T>: LinkedListNode<T> {

    required init(value: T) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}

class NonGenericCustomNode: LinkedListNode<Int> {

    required init(value: Int) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}

class LinkedList<T, U: LinkedListNode<T>> {
    var first: U? = nil
    var last: U? = nil
    var count = 0
    @discardableResult func append(_ value: T) -> U {
        let new = U(value: value)
        new.prev = last
        last?.next = new
        count += 1
        last = new
        if first == nil {
            first = new
        }
        return new
    }

    func remove(node: U) {
        node.next?.prev = node.prev
        node.prev?.next = node.next
        if node === first {
            first = first?.next as? U
        }
        if node === last {
            last = last?.prev as? U
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let list = LinkedList<Int, LinkedListNode<Int>>()
list.append(5)
print(list.first?.value)

let someCustom = LinkedList<Int, GenericCustomNode<Int>>()
someCustom.append(15)

print(someCustom.first?.value)

let otherCustom = LinkedList<Int, NonGenericCustomNode>()
otherCustom.append(2)
print(otherCustom.first?.value)
```

**Output:**

```
 Optional(5) 
 Optional(15) 
 Optional(2)
```

Comment: @Kamram Thanks. I learned how to declare what I wanted in first place. However I found that on some cases like `func remove(node: LinkedListNode<T>) {... last = last?.prev ... }` I get errors even if I change it to `func remove(node: U)`. Error: **"Cannot assign value of LinkedListNode<T>? to U?"** I think this happens because prev is declared with `var prev: LinkedListNode<T>?` type. If I where using a protocol I would declare it as `var prev: Self?` but I don't think there is an equivalent for that for concrete classes. (I have added the full remove function to the question if needed)

Comment: Yes, it's just a compiler failure not to know that `U` is actually `LinkedListNode<T>`. This can be simply fixed telling the compiler that consider `next` and `prev` as `U`. i.e, `if node === first {
            first = first?.next as? U
        }
        if node === last {
            last = last?.prev as? U
        }` *Answer* is also updated!

Comment: Kamran, Thanks for the input I think this is the best answer for subclassing. However, I decided to go for the protocol approach (just as drewag's answer). Reason is because I think the whole thing of using generics is to be get rid of casts but with current approach they cannot be avoided. If someone need my final code can be found here: https://github.com/nacho4d/DataStructures/blob/master/Sources/DataStructures/LinkedList.swift

Answer (score 1):

You will need to define a [protocol](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) with an [associated type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID189):

```
protocol Node: class {
    associatedtype Value
    var value: Value {get set}
    var next: Self? {get set}
    var prev: Self? {get set}

    init(value: Value)
}

final class BasicNode<Value>: Node {
    var value: Value
    var next: BasicNode<Value>?
    weak var prev: BasicNode<Value>?

    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

final class CustomNode<Value>: Node {
    // customize however you want
    var value: Value
    var next: BasicNode<Value>?
    weak var prev: BasicNode<Value>?

    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class LinkedList<N: Node> {
    var first: N? = nil
    var last: N? = nil
    var count = 0

    @discardableResult
    func append(_ value: N.Value) -> N {
        let new = N(value: value)
        new.prev = last
        last?.next = new
        count += 1
        last = new
        if first == nil {
            first = new
        }
        return new
    }
}
```

However, this will require using your basic linked list in an annoying way all the time:

```
let list = LinkedList<BasicNode<Int>>()
```

Depending on how you need to customize the node, I would consider finding a way to customize the behavior in the LinkList class itself using [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: thanks for the protocol approach. I tried this and it works as expected! (I just changed  `class BasicNode<Value> {` to `final class BasicNode<Value>: KNode {`). However I think there is a couple of down sides with protocols. I am not able to declare a property as `weak`. (In this case having two strongs will lead to retain cycle). Also I would like to hide the setter of `next`, `prev` and `value` properties of node to prevent corruption.

Comment: @nacho4d sorry, I forgot to make the BasicNode and CustomNode types actually implement the Node protocol. Also, the protocol itself can't declare a property as weak, but the concrete types can (and do in my code) so you don't have to worry about retain cycles. The setters being public is indeed a drawback of this solution.

Comment: In the end I decided to change my code to use this approach :) 
https://github.com/nacho4d/DataStructures/blob/master/Sources/DataStructures/LinkedList.swift